# Validate dynamic radio button in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm generating dynamic fields on view it can be any type of field

```
@foreach($inputfields as $fields)
@if($fields==1)
{{ Form::input('fields['.$fields->name.'],$Val['value']) }}                      
@else
..
.. other fields
{{ Form::radio('fields['.$fields->name.'],$Val==$Val['value'] ? true : false) }}
@endif
@endforeach
```

> controller:

```
  $Fields=[];
   $rules=[];
   foreach($request->input('fields') as $key => $fieldsval) {
    
                $ValidationString='';
                $validationData=(unserialize(array_key_first($fieldsval)));
                if($validationData['validations']=='Required')
                {
                    $ValidationString='required';
                }
        
                    $rules['fieldsval'.$key] = $ValidationString;
                    $Fields['fieldsval'.$key]=array_values($fieldsval)[0];
                   
        }
```

Issue is if i do not check the radio button then i am not able to get the value in the controller, but i want it in controller because i want to validate the fields in the controller and show respective validation error if fields not selected.

Comment: Then you need to make this field required on controler validation. And also here `{{ Form::radio('fields['.$fields->name.'],$Val==$Val['value'] ? true : false, array('required' => 'required')) }}`

Comment: @sta: No in my case i don't want to make all the fields required but selected fields based on check in controller but what is happening here if i don't check the radio button or check boxes then i don't get any information about that field so that i can validated and make it required

Comment: Then use if else condition, if check box is `true` then run the if query

Comment: @sta: In the request object i'm not getting the checkbox info, if the checkbox information is still available inspite of checkbox unchecked then i can easily use if else in controller to validate it base on other values from my database

Comment: @sta: In simple terms i need a way to get whether a checkbox/radio button is checked or not and these fields are completely dynamic

Comment: Place a hidden textbox with a 0 value before the checkbox so a 0 value is sent into the POST array.

`{{ Form::hidden('value',0) }}`

Comment: @sta: i have tried       {{ Form::hidden('fields['.$fields->name.']['.$fields->index.']','0') }} this but if i submit it with 0 then the form gets submitted and if i pass empty value in hidden then only the field gets validated

Comment: Actually I didn't get your question

Comment: @sta: I have added controller code also so that you can understand better, please have a look at the above question, my dynamic validation is working for textfield and dropdown because they are still available in the request if i don't pass any value to it but in the case of dropdown i can't get any info from the request